# How can I make grep output all the matching lines?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

Can someone explain the following grep behaviour ?

I have text a file `countries.list` (on each line there is a movie title and the country that produced the movie ).
I want to list all the lines that contain a country name.

```
command : grep "UK" countries.list | wc -l
```

> result: 55

so that means that there 55 lines that match in the file, if I dump the result to a file, obviously the file has 55 lines.

if I use :

```
command grep -c "UK" countries.list
```

> result: 223523

This means that are 223523 matches

```
wc -l countries.list  :  1956994 countries.list
```

every movie title is on a new line.

If I open why does grep "UK" `countries.list` not return all the lines.

It's obvious I am doing something wrong. Can you please help me, and explain why is this happening ?

Also if I want to print only the matched country name:

```
grep -o "UK" countries.list | wc -l
```

i get 223766 (different from 223523, but still a lot more than 55 )

Comment: grep -o "UK" will be higher because some lines may contain the text "UK" more than once and therefore will be output as multiple lines

Comment: Is your `grep` an alias, perhaps? The behavior described is definitely weird

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley it's an alias but it is not limiting anything : 
`type grep`
`grep is an alias for grep  --color=auto --exclude-dir={.bzr,CVS,.git,.hg,.svn}`

Comment: can you create a sample input file with few lines containing UK and few not containing them for us to test?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies I found the answer .
grep was opening this as binary file not as a text file.

hint : last line of `$ grep "UK" countries.list` : 
Binary file countries.list matches

if I do:
`$ strings countries.list  | grep "UK" | wc -l`
`223523`

Comment: You should rather use the `grep -a` option (force to treat as text) as `strings` modifies quite a bit what you can see from your file.